# Random dialog jQuery + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about passing a random word/phrase (on click) from a JavaScript array through to a jQuery UI dialog box?

Here's the script I have right now (I suspect I need to change body):

```
var fruits = ["Orange", "Tomato", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple Sauce", "Cherry", "Pineapple"];
var fruit = fruits[Math.floor(Math.random()*7)];

$('#sun').click(function() {
  $.dialog({
    "body":$('fruit')
    "show": true,
    "position": {
      "top": 50,
      "left: 100
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?:

```js
var fruits = ["Orange", "Tomato", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple Sauce", "Cherry", "Pineapple"];

$('#sun').click(function() {
  let fruit = fruits[Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length)];
  $('#dialog').html(fruit);
  $('#dialog').dialog();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="sun">Sun</button>
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

Comment: Only 1 issue, my button disappears after I click it once. Clicking close does not restore my button. I have tried this in Chrome, Firefox, and Pale Moon, so it's not a browser issue. Should I send my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not restricted to Dialog box then you can also use modal popup

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">...</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
```

Script:

```
var fruits = ["Orange", "Tomato", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple Sauce", "Cherry", "Pineapple"];
var fruit = fruits[Math.floor(Math.random()*fruits.length)];

$(document).ready(function () {
      
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
            $("#modalBody").html(fruit);
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```